# How can I increase the $err count manually in Powershell?

Tags: variables, powershell, error-handling, exit-code

In Powershell it is posible to increase a Variable when a Error ocours.

Per Exemple when I run this command twice the command fails (because the directory already exists) and the Error Variable now icrease to 1.

```
New-Item C:\TEMP\blabla -type directory -EA continue -EV +err
write-host $err.count

#Output: 1
```

But now to my Question:

I'd like to increase the $err variable manually but that does not work.

I tried the following:

```
switch ($LASTEXITCODE) {
    0 {
        Write-Host "Success" -ForegroundColor Green
        break
    }
    2 {
        $err.count++
        break
    }
    default {
        $err.count++
        break
    }
```

Error:
At C:\windows\mscripts\100_create_website_servicelayer.ps1:33 char:9
+             $err. <<<< count++
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$err` has a count property just because is of type `array`.

You can try to add some string to `$err` in each case:

```
2 {
        $err += "Error"
        break
    }
default {
        $err += "Error"
        break
    }
```